# How can I provide user feedback when a draggable is rejected by a droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

jQuery 1.3
jQuery UI 1.7.2

I have an application where there are a number of droppable divs that accept only a single draggable.  I do this by setting the accept option on all my droppable's to a function that check for a valid draggable and if it is already occupied.  If it is occupied, the accept function returns false, else it returns true.  Thus if a user tries to drop a draggable on a droppable that is already occupied, the draggable reverts.

What I would like to do is provide additional feedback when a user drops a draggable on top of an occupied droppable.  Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Check the length of dropped objects, if its > 0 then it means its occupied and you can alert or whatever feedback you want to give.

e.g 

if($(this).children(".dropped_object").length > 0) return false

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this with a class?  Set the parent item with the class 'full' when you drop the dragged element.  Then you could do something like:

```
if($this).hasClass('full'))
    //Alert user it is full
```

Comment: The problem is I need to make this check when the draggable is not accepted and dropped over an occupied droppable.  The accept option of droppable, when given a function, will fire on mouse move for all droppable's so that's no good and the drop event of droppable will only fire if accepted.

What I need to do is take action when the draggable is not accepted and dropped over a droppable that is occupied.